# How to "manually" forward IP traffic in local network

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, ip, forwarding

Im a student and as a hobby I am writing a program that is supposed to perform a man in the middle attack with ARP spoofing, and then manipulate the traffic before sending it on to the victim. For this I need to examine the packets, manipulate them and forward them to my victim.

Note: This is strictly a hobby project and the network is my own local network at home. Its just some generic AT&T homeportal and a bunch of machines connected via wireless.

I know that when I enable IP forwarding on my machine, it does the following to packets that are to be forwarded:

```
Put my MAC as SRC in the ethernet header
Put forwarding target's MAC as DST in ethernet header
Decrement TTL
Recalculate IP Header checksum
Send the packet
```

Since I want to manipulate the traffic before sending it on, I am trying to write a program that does the manipulation and then the forwarding manually so to speak. What I tried to do:

```
See if packet is for my victim
If so, manipulate it how I want
Put my homeportals MAC address as SRC in the eth header
Put my victims MAC as DST in eth header
Send the packet
```

My train of thought was that when looking at the packets it would be indistinguishable from "normal" traffic. If I decrement the TTL and recalc. the checksum and put in my machines MAC as SRC, its kinda easy to notice whats going on if you look at the packets.

However, my method does not work. As in, if I put the homeportals MAC as SRC on the ethernet header, for some reason none of the webpages load on machine A.

If I put in my machines mac address, the webpages load although slowly and wireshark shows me a lot of TCP retransmissions coming from the webpages server, I am guessing this is because my program is forwarding the packet too slowly to machine A and so A can't respond in time?

So anyway, thats pretty much my question: Why can't I pretend to be the homeportal? As in put its MAC address in the ethernet header of the packets I forward to A. Also, what else could cause all the retranmissions from the webpage servers when I use my machines MAC address? English isn't my first language so I hope this is not too vague.